# Formatter include third party moment.js

Tags: sapui5, momentjs, formatter

I have a problem to use the third party library moment.js in our formatter.

**formatter.js**
This is a working way:

```
sap.ui.define([], function() {
    "use strict";
    return {
        moment: jQuery.sap.require("name.de.tbase1.model.moment"),
```

This don't:

```
sap.ui.define([
    "name/de/tbase1/model/moment"
], function(moment) {
    "use strict";
    return {
        moment: moment
```

If I use the second option, then lib is loaded fine, but I get this error:
*sinon.js:175 Uncaught TypeError: Fake XHR onreadystatechange handler threw exception: moment is not a function*

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem.

```
sap.ui.define([
    "name/de/tbase1/model/moment"
], function(Moment) {
    "use strict";
    return {
        moment: Moment,
```

Comment: I'm not sure what happens in "name/de/tbase1/model/moment" but I'm loading moment.js without passing anything to the factory function. Then I just return the global variable. At least this is what is covered by the documentation: https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.html#.define

Comment: If I do it on your way, than I get this error: "Uncaught TypeError: Fake XHR onreadystatechange handler threw exception: Moment is not a function". But thanks for your link, will further check for it.